Using UE_LOG in a Plugin
I am working on a plugin for Unreal Engine. In it, I use UE_LOG with a custom log category named "Goap".
In DebugGame build everything is OK. However in any Editor build in the .cpp file for the actor that uses the plugin code I get this linker error:
"unresolved external symbol "struct FLogCategoryGoap...".
I have placed DECLARE_LOG_CATEGORY_EXTERN macro into my titular plugin .h file, and DEFINE_LOG_CATEGORY macro into the .cpp file. Also, I have included the header itno every file that uses the category

Editor builds cannot directly access code/types defined in dynamic plugins, since the type does not exist at build (during the link phase) time.
Only GameDebug and GameRelease builds allow access to plugins.
If you are trying to build the editor with additional functionality, it must be done either: statically,
or possibly as Editor extension code within the plugin itself.
